# Byte Array to Short value and vice-versa in Objective-c(iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I converted Byte array(NSMutableData) to short value.

```
+(short)byteArrayToShort:(NSMutableData *)paRawBytes offset:(int)piOffset{

int iRetVal = -1;

int8_t *byteArray = [paRawBytes mutableBytes];

int iLow;
int iHigh;

if(CFByteOrderGetCurrent() == CFByteOrderBigEndian)
{
    iLow  = byteArray[piOffset + 1];
    iHigh = byteArray[piOffset + 0];
}
else
{
    iLow  = byteArray[piOffset + 0];
    iHigh = byteArray[piOffset + 1];
}

// Merge high-order and low-order byte to form a 16-bit double value.
iRetVal = (iHigh << 8) | (0xFF & iLow);

return (short)iRetVal;
}
```

Is this correct way in iOS?

Ans also,  I converted Short value to Byte array(NSMutableData).

```
+(int8_t *)shortToByteArray:(short)piValueToConvert
{
int8_t * aRetVal;

Byte iLowest;
Byte iHigh;

iLowest = (Byte)(piValueToConvert & 0xFF);
iHigh    = (Byte)((piValueToConvert >> 8) & 0xFF);

if(CFByteOrderGetCurrent() == CFByteOrderBigEndian)
{
    aRetVal[1] = iLowest;
    aRetVal[0] = iHigh;
}
else
{
    aRetVal[0] = iLowest;
    aRetVal[1] = iHigh;
}


return aRetVal;
```

}

Please suggest me is this correct way or not...
Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose that would depend on the format that the data was originally stored in your `NSMutableData`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. but watever data will come i have to convert into short valu

Comment: Which endian of the byte array, little or big ? Your code suppose it is local endian, but the data may come from network which maybe big-endian.